Typescript extract every type from tuple except rest
We have posible tuple to receive types:
type Args = [number, string, ...number[]];
type Args = [...number[]];
type Args = [];

How to extract types before rest type?
Update:
by "extracting" I mean removing rest types from tuple and creating a new tuple with the remaining types.
To get as a result:
type new Args = [number, string]
type new Args = []
type new Args = []

And it is necessary that this happens dynamically, I don’t know in advance how many arguments to pull out there will be, there may be no arguments, but maybe only a spread argument.
Example code to use:
type SomeObj = {
  a: [number, string, ...nums[]],
  b: [...number[]],
  c: [],
}

type FilterRest<T extends any[]> = /* Logic to extract types */;

type FromObj<Key: string> = FilterRest<SomeObj[Key]>;

FromObj<'a'> // [number, string]


What do you mean by "extract"?

"By extract i mean get in result" It's still not clear.

"And it is necessary that this happens dynamically..." TypeScript's type system is extremely rich and complex, but it is a static type system. Types are known at compile-time (even generics, mostly). You can't create TypeScript types using runtime (dynamic) information. Since it's static, you'll always know what Args is in advance. Perhaps this is an X/Y problem and you'd be best off deleting this question and asking a new one describing in detail the problem you're trying to solve...?

It's not clear what you mean by "extract," but for instance you can get the type of the first element of the tuple via Args[0]:
type Args = [number, string, ...number[]];
type First = Args[0];

In that example, First is number.
You can extend that to get the first two tuple types as a new tuple:
type Args = [number, string, ...number[]];
type FirstTwo = [Args[0], Args[1]];

FirstTwo is [number, string].
